# Why I can't get data from PHP using react native?

Tags: php, react-native

I had a mobile application that I developed with react native and php(backend with sqlServer data) but recently, I wanted to run my application but I had a problem :

When I click a button that normally has to show me what information that I have in my php file, I got nothing (even an empty alert is not showin, I don't know if the problem is with fetch method!!),

this is my code:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.userRegister}><Text>Connexion</Text></TouchableOpacity>

  userRegister = () =>{
   fetch('http://192.168.1.21/recup.php',{
   method:'post',
   header:{
   'Accept':'application/json',
   'Content-type' :'application/json'
   },
   body:JSON.stringify({})})
   .then((responseData)=>responseData.text())
   .then((responseJson)=>{
       alert(responseJson)
   })
   .catch((error)=>{console.error(error);})
   }
```

for my php file works well (when I use http://192.168.1.21/recup.php in my browser I get "data matched")

```
<?php 
$serverName="DESKTOP-T5SLVUB\SQL2008R2";
$connectionInfo=array("Database"=>"","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"");
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);


   if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

echo('data matched')
?>
```

If someone had the same issue or know why I got this problem ,

Comment: could be cors, what debugging have you done?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment, Can you clarify please

Comment: The console.error is firing but unless your looking at some tool to debug in your mobile app emulator etc you wont see it . change it to `alert(error)` or handle/debug it correctly, your most likely see it spit out some cors (cross-origin resource sharing) error which you can then google for a solution

Comment: also unless your phone/app is on the same LAN network `192.168.1.*` won't work

Comment: I change it to alert(error) but get nothing

Comment: does the `console.error()` line give you an error message

Comment: no I have no error in my console. I don't know whats wrong It used to work perfectley before